# Send logs to s3 - Official Airflow Helm Chart + KubernetesExecutor

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the [official Airflow Helm Chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) to deploy KubernetesExecutor (still locally) on a KinD Cluster.

Because this is a Helm Chart, I'm having a lot of trouble trying to configure anything that are not explicitly shown at the documentation.

Using this scenario, I want to send all my logs data produced by my DAGs to a s3 bucket (which is a common thing to do on the airflow stack).

The problem is: there's nothing on the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/manage-logs.html) and even on other threads that can help me achieve this.

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Did you see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow#option-2a---remote-s3-bucket-recommended-on-aws) ?

Comment: Could you please try solution [presented on this website](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow#option-2a---remote-s3-bucket-recommended-on-aws) -> *How to persist airflow logs?* -> *Option 2a - Remote S3 Bucket (recommended on AWS)* and let know the results?

Comment: The solution presented on both of your comments are for the user community manteined airflow helm chart, not the official one. I've already founded it on my reseachers and it does not apply for my environment. I've already tried to use this not official helm chart with KubernetesExecutor, but no lucky.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly your problem is, but the following values.yaml works for me with the official airflow helm chart:

```
config:
  logging:
    # Airflow can store logs remotely in AWS S3. Users must supply a remote
    # location URL (starting with either 's3://...') and an Airflow connection
    # id that provides access to the storage location.
    remote_logging: 'True'
    #colored_console_log : 'True'
    remote_base_log_folder : "s3://PATH"
    # the following connection must be created in the airflow web ui
    remote_log_conn_id : 'S3Conn'
    # Use server-side encryption for logs stored in S3
    encrypt_s3_logs : 'True'
```